# Rename files from lower to upper with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I rename many files from lower to upper?
For example a file named `example.txt` to `EXAMPLE.txt`

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `pathlib` for this. You'll have to modify this to suit your needs - In this example I'm just using `pathlib.Path.glob` to iterate through all `.txt` files in the current working directory:

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path(".").glob("*.txt"):
    path.rename(f"{path.stem.upper()}{path.suffix}")
```

Answer (score 0):

For easy solution, you can try:

```py
import os

fileName = 'example.txt'

def toUpper(fileName): 
    tempName = fileName.split('.') 
    return (tempName[0].upper() + '.' + tempName[1])

os.rename(fileName, toUpper(fileName))
```

It won't work if your file name has multiple dots.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import os

def get_name(original_file_name):
    name, ext = (re.match('(.*)(\.[^.]+)', original_file_name).groups())
    return name.upper() + ext


def rename_file(original_file_name):
    os.rename(original_file_name, get_name(original_file_name))
```